# Cannot create inner bean, SpringBatch StaxEventItemReader

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, spring-batch

Please help me how to solve this error when executing a Job reading an XML file with SpringBatch and StaxEventItemReader, the error is: **cannot create inner bean (inner bean)#4097d7fe of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key[0] nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationAxception**

**-> context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">
  <job id="PKREJ005-01-PE" incrementer="defaultIncrementer" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <description>Job to generate report</description>
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="interceptorJobExecutionListener"/>
    </listeners>

    <step id="idStep01" parent="step01"></step>

  </job>
    <step id="step01">
      <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="xmlItemReader" processor="xmlItemProcessor" writer="xmlItemWriter" commit-interval="2"></chunk>
      </tasklet>
    </step>

</beans:beans>
```

**-> bean.xml**

```
<bean id="customUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.bbva.pkre.dto.accounting.amp.AMP</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemProcessor" class="com.bbva.pkre.batch.process.AMPItemProcess" />
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="com.bbva.pkre.batch.writer.AMPItemWriter" />
```

**Error:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHGVg.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, the exception is a `ClassNotFoundException`. Make sure the `spring-batch-infrastructure` jar (which contains the `StaxEventItemReader` class) is in the classpath of your application.